# Span text across columns in Flow Document

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am redesigning my instant messaging apps chat interface to be a flow document. Here is the design I am trying to replicate.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RysGv.jpg

Here is what I have tried so far using XamlPad. My main problems are alignment and/or column spanning. Edit: Newest attempt at the top

```
<TabControl Width="500">

    <TabItem Header="Julien Rosen">

        <FlowDocument>

            <Table>

                <Table.Columns>

                    <TableColumn Width="60" />
                    <TableColumn />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />

                </Table.Columns>

                <TableRowGroup>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TableCell RowSpan="2">
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Image Source="c:\logo.png" Height="35" />
                                <LineBreak />
                                <Image Margin="0,5,5,0" Source="c:\file.png" Height="10" />
                                <Image Source="c:\flag-green.png" Height="10" />
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>

                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TableCell>

                            <Paragraph FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12">
                                <TextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="False" Background="Transparent" IsEnabled="False">
                                    Julien Rosen:
                                </TextBox>
                                <TextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="False" Background="Transparent" IsEnabled="False">
                                    03/01/2013 14:17
                                </TextBox>      
                            </Paragraph>

                            <Paragraph Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="12">
                                This is a new attempt using rows differently
                            </Paragraph>

                        </TableCell>

                    </TableRow>

                </TableRowGroup>

            </Table>

            <Table>

                <Table.Columns>

                    <TableColumn Width="60" />
                    <TableColumn />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />

                </Table.Columns>

                <TableRowGroup>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Image Source="c:\logo.png" Height="35" />
                                <LineBreak />
                                <Image Margin="0,5,5,0" Source="c:\file.png" Height="10" />
                                <Image Source="c:\flag-green.png" Height="10" />
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>

                        <TableCell>

                            <Paragraph FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12">
                                <TextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="False" Background="Transparent" IsEnabled="False">
                                    Julien Rosen:
                                </TextBox>
                            </Paragraph>

                            <Paragraph Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="12">
                                Long messages end at the end at the cell wall instead of continuing underneath the date, regardless of ColumnSpan being set on the TableCell
                            </Paragraph>

                        </TableCell>

                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12">
                                <TextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="False" Background="Transparent" IsEnabled="False">
                                    03/01/2013 14:17
                                </TextBox>                                      
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>

                    </TableRow>

                </TableRowGroup>

            </Table>

            <Table>

                <Table.Columns>

                    <TableColumn Width="60" />
                    <TableColumn />

                </Table.Columns>

                <TableRowGroup>

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Image Source="c:\logo.png" Height="35" />
                                <LineBreak />
                                <Image Margin="0,5,5,0" Source="c:\file.png" Height="10" />
                                <Image Source="c:\flag-green.png" Height="10" />
                            </Paragraph>
                        </TableCell>

                        <TableCell>

                            <Paragraph>
                                <Figure HorizontalAnchor="PageLeft">

                                    <Paragraph FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12">
                                        <TextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="False" Background="Transparent" IsEnabled="False">
                                            Julien Rosen:
                                        </TextBox>
                                    </Paragraph>

                                </Figure>

                                <Figure HorizontalAnchor="PageRight">

                                    <Paragraph FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12">
                                        <TextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="False" Background="Transparent" IsEnabled="False">
                                            03/01/2013 14:17
                                        </TextBox>                                      
                                    </Paragraph>

                            </Figure>
                            </Paragraph>


                            <Paragraph Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="12">
                                This style tries to use figures, which messes up the alignment and does crazy stuff with the text, but at least the text continues under the date
                            </Paragraph>

                        </TableCell>

                    </TableRow>

                </TableRowGroup>

            </Table>

        </FlowDocument>

    </TabItem>

</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried to come up with a sample that you can expand upon. I've used shadings to give you an idea of which cell / row is doing what in the table.

```
<Window x:Class="JulienSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="AvatarImage" UriSource="https://shop.blindferret.com/uploads/products/339af7124f5be1c660107332475fd6038742e1e0.jpg" DecodePixelHeight="96" DecodePixelWidth="72"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="FlagImage" UriSource="flag.png" DecodePixelHeight="18" DecodePixelWidth="18" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="FileImage" UriSource="file.png" DecodePixelHeight="18" DecodePixelWidth="18" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <TabControl Width="500">
        <TabItem Header="Julien Rosen">
            <FlowDocumentReader ViewingMode="Scroll" IsPageViewEnabled="False" IsPrintEnabled="False" IsTwoPageViewEnabled="False">
                <FlowDocument FontFamily="Segoe UI" >
                    <Table BorderBrush="CadetBlue" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Table.Columns>
                            <TableColumn Width="100"/>
                            <TableColumn Width="100" />
                            <TableColumn />
                            <TableColumn Width="100" />
                        </Table.Columns>
                        <TableRowGroup>
                            <TableRow Background="AntiqueWhite">
                                <TableCell RowSpan="2">
                                    <BlockUIContainer>
                                        <Image Source="{StaticResource AvatarImage}" Width="72" Height="96"/>
                                    </BlockUIContainer>
                                </TableCell>

                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>Julien Rosen</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>

                                <TableCell Background="Chartreuse"></TableCell>

                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>07/03/2013</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>

                            <TableRow Background="Aquamarine">
                                <TableCell ColumnSpan="3" RowSpan="3">
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        Long messages end at the end at the cell wall instead of continuing underneath the date, regardless of ColumnSpan being set on the TableCell
                                    Long messages end at the end at the cell wall instead of continuing underneath the date, regardless of ColumnSpan being set on the TableCell
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow Background="BurlyWood">
                                <TableCell Background="DarkGreen">
                                    <BlockUIContainer>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource FlagImage}" Height="18" Width="18"/>
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource FileImage}" Height="18" Width="18"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </BlockUIContainer>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell />
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableRowGroup>
                    </Table>
                    <Table BorderBrush="CadetBlue" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Table.Columns>
                            <TableColumn Width="100"/>
                            <TableColumn Width="100" />
                            <TableColumn />
                            <TableColumn Width="100" />
                        </Table.Columns>
                        <TableRowGroup>
                            <TableRow Background="AntiqueWhite">
                                <TableCell RowSpan="2">
                                    <BlockUIContainer>
                                        <Image Source="{StaticResource AvatarImage}" Width="72" Height="96"/>
                                    </BlockUIContainer>
                                </TableCell>

                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>Julien Rosen</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>

                                <TableCell Background="Chartreuse"></TableCell>

                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph>07/03/2013</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>

                            <TableRow Background="Aquamarine">
                                <TableCell ColumnSpan="3" RowSpan="3">
                                    <Paragraph>
                                        Long messages end at the end at the cell wall instead of continuing underneath the date, regardless of ColumnSpan being set on the TableCell
                                    Long messages end at the end at the cell wall instead of continuing underneath the date, regardless of ColumnSpan being set on the TableCell
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow Background="BurlyWood">
                                <TableCell Background="DarkGreen">
                                    <BlockUIContainer>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource FlagImage}" Height="18" Width="18"/>
                                            <Image Source="{StaticResource FileImage}" Height="18" Width="18"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </BlockUIContainer>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell />
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableRowGroup>
                    </Table>                </FlowDocument>
            </FlowDocumentReader>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

And it will result in:

[image: Screenshot]